# Function result Complex type serialization OData 6.0.0

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api2, odata

**I updated OData version to 6.0.0.**

Before update i had a function declaration like:

```
var getResult = odataBuilder.EntityType<Customer>().Collection.Function("GetResult");
    getResult.Parameter<int>("Number");
    getResult.Returns<ResultDto>();
```

ResultDto has structure:

```
    public class ResultDto
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public IList<ResultComponentsDto> ResultComponentsDtos { get; set; }
}
```

ResultComponentsDto has structure:

```
    public class ResultComponentsDto
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Where Product is an entity.

The function will return the correct data as:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetResult(int number)
    {
        var result = new ResultDto
        {
            CustomerName = "Test",
            ResultComponentsDtos = new List<ResultComponentsDto>
            {
                new ResultComponentsDto
                {
                    Description = "Test 1",
                    Products = new List<Product>
                    {
                        new Product
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Name = "1"
                        },
                        new Product
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Name = "2"
                        },
                    }
                },
                new ResultComponentsDto
                {
                    Description = "Test 2",
                    Products = new List<Product>
                    {
                        new Product
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Name = "3"
                        },
                        new Product
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Name = "4"
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

My problem is after the update i will not get the full result, i only get the following result serialized:

```
    {  
   "@odata.context":"http://localhost:3721/$metadata#WebApi.Dto.ResultDto",
   "CustomerName":"Test",
   "ResultComponentsDtos":[  
      {  
         "Description":"Test 1"
      },
      {  
         "Description":"Test 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

The collection of products inside ResultComponentsDto is not being serialized, before update this worked. As the serializer for complex type has changed:
[see here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-07-MergeComplexAndEntityReadWriter) What would be the way to achieve the same results as in the previous version?

**What i tried:**

1. Enable query parameter: 
   [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 4)]
2. Configuring the complext type in the model builder with autoexpand set to true:

   ```
           var result = odataBuilder.ComplexType<ResultDto>();
       result.Property(r => r.CustomerName);
       var resultComponents = result.CollectionProperty(r => r.ResultComponentsDtos);
       resultComponents.AutoExpand = true;

       var resultComponentsComplexType = odataBuilder.ComplexType<ResultComponentsDto>();
       resultComponentsComplexType.Property(rc => rc.Description);
       var products = resultComponentsComplexType.HasMany(rc => rc.Products);
       products.AutoExpand = true;
       products.AutomaticallyExpand(false);
   ```
3. Use autoexpand attribute: 
   [AutoExpand]
   public IList Products { get; set; }
4. Manual expand in request (unsing $expand), this is not working currently for complext types.

Thanks in advance,
Mihai

Comment: did you sort this problem out? We updated to OData 6.0.0 and we are facing the same exact problem

Comment: No problem still open, i have made an issue at github: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/880 you can check status there, it is in progress but i did not receive any feedback yet

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
i suggest you that change output result to string. such as bellow.
getResult.Returns< string > ();

Then in getResult method convert result object to json string.
return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result))

In client you must DeSerialize output string to object.

Comment: Hi, This would really be no solution for me, as i am working with potentially a lot of DTO's, registering each one as an Entity beats the purpose and can potentially confuse the consumer of the service.

Comment: I think ODATA only serialize entities by default. of course maybe can write custom sterilizer class for a complex type class.

Comment: How would you write a custom serializer @AhmadrezaFarrokhnejad?